# How to plot pies or histograms around points (GeoPandas) containing different level values indicators?

Tags: geopandas, chart, plot, histogram

This is my code (a simple sample of df). I'd like to have around each point on a map, an histogram or pie showing the mechanical bikes out of the total.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    {'station_code' : ['13014', '13011' , '13012'], 
     'numbikesavailable' : ['25', '15', '20'], 
     'mechanical' : ['10', '5' , '8'], 
     'geometry' : 
         ['POINT (2.36404 48.84252)', 
          'POINT (2.35822 48.83541)' , 
          'POINT (2.40932 48.8691)']
    }
  )
```

How can I do this?

Comment: it seem you are trying to create pie or histogram graph rather than a buffer, if you want answer you should clarify and update your title

Comment: yes sorry, i'm new here. I put the code hope in the right place. many thx